# PostGIS partition table by POLYGON geometry

Tags: postgresql, postgis, database-partitioning

Hello my fellow postgis users,

I am in need of your help!

I have a table that has a geometry of type POLYGON that I would like to partition to make queries more efficient. As the main condition for the searches is a WHERE clause of type ST_Intersects with an AOI, I thought this would be a good idea. (please advise if not)

I have searched and found little or old information regarding partitioning a table on geometry.

I am trying to use a PARTITION BY RANGE on the geometry column but I am having a few issues.

I read that PostGIS can sort geometries and so I prepared a grid of points for the FROM-TO values of the partitions.

- The first problem was that I could not mix POINT in this clause because it was a different type of geometry, so I instead used POLYGON that has al vertex as the same point (puaj!).
- Second, I find that the ordering of this grid is not what I expected and so I have not been able to successfully build al the needed partitions.
- Third, I am doubting this to be a viable solution as there may be records in which the geometries may span more than one of the regions I selected for partitioning and so they would not belong to any partition or to multiple partitions (not acceptable).

Do you I have a future here or should I give up completely on geometry partitioning this table? Thanks!!

Following a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE usercare.product_catalog (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    geom public.geometry(polygon, 4326) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT product_catalog_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, geom)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (geom);

CREATE TABLE product_catalog_A1 PARTITION OF product_catalog for VALUES FROM (ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((-135 67.5, -135 67.5, -135 67.5, -135 67.5))',4326)) TO (ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON ((-180 90, -180 90, -180 90, -180 90))',4326));
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work, unless your queries are for < = > or BETWEEN on the geometry, which seems unlikely.  You could probably do something with inheritance-based partitioning, but you would have to manually come up with the boundaries and route the rows.  That would be a pain, and likely wouldn't improve performance anyway.

Comment: @jjanes, I was afraid this would be the case. But I really think that partitioning using AOIs could potentially benefit performance. The partitioning condition should be a geometric operation (includes, intersects, etc) and that brings up the issue of how to do it properly. I think this has been solved in the mapping X/Y/Z standard. Partitioning and sub partitioning up until the wanted level using the geometric operation of choice. What I am afraid of is the complexity vs benefits of this approach. Any comments on this?

Comment: Also, what about HASH partitioning using the geometry?

Comment: postgis doesn't provide a built in hash function, so you would have to come up with one.  It is not obvious how this would help, anyway.

Comment: Your description of partitioning AOIs is pretty much what GiST indexes already do.  Reimplementing the top layer or two layers or the GiST index in your own partitioning structure doesn't seem like it would  be an improvement.  True, you are partitioning the table data and not just the index data, but does that matter?  It could improve caching/locality, but for that to be highly effective your partition structure would need to closely align with your pattern of queries.  You haven't described such a pattern we could use, though.

Comment: Hey there @jjanes, queries are from the gui in the form of st_intersects in the where clause. I think from what said that there's no better way than what gist offers for geom type or that it has to be extremely fine tuned.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table that stores GIS data throughout the world. What I did was partition that table by 30° latitude and longitude ranges, covering the whole earth from 90°S to 90°N and 180°W to 180°E. Then in your code, you need to decide how to get the correct tables for insert and query transactions.

I included the SQL file here.

Please note: It's very long and consists of 5 sections. The first is where the tables are created. The second is for adding primary key to each table (required for inherited tables). The remaining ones are for indexes and triggers.

```
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n0e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n30e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n60e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n90e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n120e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n150e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n0w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n30w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n60w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n90w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n120w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0n150w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n0e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n30e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n60e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n90e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n120e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n150e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n0w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n30w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n60w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n90w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n120w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30n150w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n0e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n30e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n60e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n90e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n120e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n150e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n0w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n30w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n60w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n90w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n120w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60n150w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s0e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s30e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s60e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s90e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s120e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s150e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s0w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s30w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s60w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s90w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s120w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_0s150w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s0e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s30e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s60e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s90e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s120e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s150e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s0w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s30w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s60w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s90w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s120w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_30s150w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s0e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s30e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s60e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s90e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s120e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s150e () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s0w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s30w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s60w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s90w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s120w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);
CREATE TABLE gis_data.data_60s150w () INHERITS (gis_data.base_table);

ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n0e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n30e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n60e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n90e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n120e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n150e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n0w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n30w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n60w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n90w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n120w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0n150w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n0e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n30e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n60e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n90e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n120e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n150e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n0w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n30w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n60w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n90w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n120w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30n150w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n0e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n30e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n60e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n90e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n120e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n150e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n0w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n30w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n60w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n90w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n120w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60n150w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s0e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s30e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s60e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s90e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s120e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s150e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s0w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s30w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s60w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s90w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s120w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_0s150w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s0e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s30e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s60e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s90e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s120e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s150e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s0w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s30w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s60w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s90w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s120w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_30s150w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s0e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s30e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s60e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s90e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s120e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s150e ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s0w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s30w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s60w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s90w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s120w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE gis_data.data_60s150w ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE INDEX data_0n0e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n0e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n30e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n30e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n60e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n60e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n90e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n90e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n120e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n120e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n150e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n150e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n0w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n0w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n30w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n30w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n60w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n60w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n90w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n90w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n120w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n120w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0n150w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0n150w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n0e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n0e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n30e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n30e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n60e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n60e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n90e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n90e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n120e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n120e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n150e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n150e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n0w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n0w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n30w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n30w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n60w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n60w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n90w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n90w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n120w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n120w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30n150w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30n150w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n0e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n0e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n30e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n30e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n60e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n60e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n90e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n90e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n120e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n120e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n150e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n150e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n0w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n0w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n30w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n30w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n60w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n60w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n90w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n90w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n120w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n120w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60n150w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60n150w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s0e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s0e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s30e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s30e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s60e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s60e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s90e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s90e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s120e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s120e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s150e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s150e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s0w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s0w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s30w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s30w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s60w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s60w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s90w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s90w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s120w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s120w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_0s150w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_0s150w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s0e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s0e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s30e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s30e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s60e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s60e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s90e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s90e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s120e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s120e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s150e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s150e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s0w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s0w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s30w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s30w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s60w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s60w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s90w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s90w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s120w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s120w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_30s150w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_30s150w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s0e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s0e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s30e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s30e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s60e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s60e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s90e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s90e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s120e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s120e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s150e_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s150e USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s0w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s0w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s30w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s30w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s60w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s60w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s90w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s90w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s120w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s120w USING GIST (primary);
CREATE INDEX data_60s150w_ix_primary ON gis_data.data_60s150w USING GIST (primary);

CREATE INDEX data_0n0e_ix_creator_user_id ON gis_data.data_0n0e (creator_user_id);
CREATE INDEX data_0n30e_ix_creator_user_id ON gis_data.data_0n30e (creator_user_id);
CREATE INDEX data_0n60e_ix_creator_user_id ON gis_data.data_0n60e (creator_user_id);
CREATE INDEX data_0n90e_ix_creator_user_id ON gis_data.data_0n90e (creator_user_id);
...

CREATE TRIGGER RS_gis_data_TR_data_0n0e_BI BEFORE INSERT ON gis_data.data_0n0e FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger('{"gis_data"}', 'data_0n0e', 8);
CREATE TRIGGER RS_gis_data_TR_data_0n30e_BI BEFORE INSERT ON gis_data.data_0n30e FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger('{"gis_data"}', 'data_0n30e', 8);
CREATE TRIGGER RS_gis_data_TR_data_0n60e_BI BEFORE INSERT ON gis_data.data_0n60e FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger('{"gis_data"}', 'data_0n60e', 8);
CREATE TRIGGER RS_gis_data_TR_data_0n90e_BI BEFORE INSERT ON gis_data.data_0n90e FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger('{"gis_data"}', 'data_0n90e', 8);
...
```